How can I automate filling down "=importxml" in google sheets?
Edit: I read through a similar post for script on copy and pasting values.
However,the importxml function has variable load times. I don't want the script to copy and paste values while the formula is still "loading".
I also am asking for clarification on how to implement paste values in my current script so that formulas that finish loading are pasted as values and then the importxml is filled down. (I am not a programer). Thank you so much!
I am fetching information from thousands of URLs using Import XML. Currently, I've been filling the formula down a set number of rows (say rows 3-53). I wait for the data to populate and then I copy/paste rows 3-52 as values before dragging the formula down from 53 to 103. I've tried writing app script with delays and triggers to automate this, but the I can't get the script to paste data that's loaded in as values. The data just disappears after the script is run.
I've also tried writing script to just fill down a few rows every other minute. However, that keeps the loading of the importxml function slow. Is there some way to automate this formula filling process with delays so the data can load in? My code is below
function fillFormulasAndWait() {
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Sheet1'); // Change to your sheet name
  const lastRow = sheet.getRange('I:I').getValues().filter(String).length; // Get the last populated row in column I
  let row = 3;

  while (row <= lastRow) {
    // Fill formulas in P, M, N, and O columns for the current row and the next row
    fillFormulas(sheet, row, row + 1);

    // Wait 20 seconds before processing the next set
    Utilities.sleep(20000); // 20 seconds delay

    // Move to the next set of rows
    row += 2;
  }
}

function fillFormulas(sheet, startRow, endRow) {
  // Copy the formulas from row 3 to the specified range
  const sourceRange = sheet.getRange('M3:O3');
  sourceRange.copyTo(sheet.getRange(`M${startRow}:O${endRow}`));
  
  const sourceRangeP = sheet.getRange('P3');
  sourceRangeP.copyTo(sheet.getRange(`P${startRow}:P${endRow}`));
}

// Create a time-driven trigger to run the function every minute
function createTrigger() {
  ScriptApp.newTrigger('fillFormulasAndWait')
    .timeBased()
    .everyMinutes(1)
    .create();
}

// Delete all existing triggers
function deleteTriggers() {
  const allTriggers = ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers();
  for (let i = 0; i < allTriggers.length; i++) {
    ScriptApp.deleteTrigger(allTriggers[i]);
  }
}

// Set up the script to run
function setup() {
  deleteTriggers();
  createTrigger();
}

